# How do I tame and ride the undead horses?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So the 15.0 update came out for minecraft pocket edition. Well along with horses there are also the zombie horse and skeleton horse. Is it possible to tame these? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you spawn one using a spawn egg for example, it won't work. However, they do spawn naturally, but only during a thunderstorm. In these situations, they are referred to as "Trap Skeleton Horses".

To be able to ride them, they need to be struck by lightning, which will cause them to split into 4-5 mounted skeletons. Fortunately, all you need to do is walk within 10 blocks of a lone skeleton horse, to trigger the trap (they will automatically be struck by lightning when this occurs). Kill the skeletons, and the horse will then be ride-able, and you can then tame it by giving it a saddle.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Skeleton_Horse#Skeleton_trap)

Zombie horses however cannot be ridden if spawned by the player unless the following command is used (Java Edition only):

```
/summon minecraft:zombie_horse ~ ~ ~ {Tame:1b}
```

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie_Horse#Taming)

Answer (score 1):

Here is tutorial of how to tame and ride a horse, put saddle or armor on horse and get off it. Anyway, I feel much easier to tame horse in Minecraft minecraft pocket edition than in Minecraft PC.
Step 1: Spawn a horse with horse spawn egg.
Step 2: Tame a Horse with Gold Apple, Gold Carrots
Step 3: Ride a Horse by taping it with Empty Hand
Step 4: Put a horse armor and saddle on horse in MCPE 0.15
Step 5: Get off horse in MCPE 0.15

```
    Method 1: Use Sneak (double tap the center button on left side control)  
    Method 2: Ride the horse and jump into water, double tap the right   button and fly high away from horse. ( this silly method is figured out by myself before haven’t got the first way)
```

For all details and HD image instructions you can visit [here](http://www.goplay.com/article/how-to-tame-horse-ride-horse-in-minecraft-pe-0.15-horse-taming-guide-1597.html).

Answer (score 0):

The skeleton horses only spawn if a horse is struck by lightning. You can't ride them if you use a spawn egg. To get on the skeleton horse, you have to be holding a golden carrot, then tame the horse and put a saddle on. The zombie horses don't spawn in minecraft pocket edition unless the player spawns them manually.

Answer (score 0):

A skeleton horse will be tamed, and ridable, if you hold a hay bale to it. However, I think this is only possible if it was spawned.

Comment: This is absolutely, positively, 100% wrong.  Skeleton horses can not be fed or bred, as per the official Minecraft wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Undead horses can spawn naturally, you don't have to use eggs. They just need to be struck by lightning.

If you kill the skeletons that are riding the horse you can ride it.

Answer (score 0):

Once a skeleton was riding a skeleton horse, I killed the skeleton and rode the skeleton horse, So you can probably do that to.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which type of undead horse you are referring to. Zombie horses do not spawn naturally in PE, at least not yet, and I dont believe you can tame them after manually spawning them. Skeleton horses, however, spawn naturally from "skeleton traps", which are a seemingly normal horse walking around during a storm. But when you get close to it, lightning will strike it, turning it into 3-4 skeleton horses with skeletons riding on them. The skeletons have enchanted armor, but if you kill them you can tame the skeleton horses they ride on.